# Simulate keypress on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery and i want to make my own start page.

Unfortunately I will have to click the searchbar/omnibox (chrome) every time I want to search. Can I automate this with JavaScript/jQuery? Pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> will focus on the search bar.

What I want: JavaScript/jQuery simulating <kbd>F6</kbd> keypress on document ready.
Code I did found that I can't get to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 117}));
});
```

117 is the keycode for <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a good reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: No, scripts cannot move the focus to the address bar.

Comment: My end goal is that I am able to search on google after opening the page without clicking in the searchbox or pressing any buttons. Btw thanks for the fast replies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't do this**, simply because it's outside the scope of what a webpage should be doing and unsurprisingly Chrome prevents this behaviour.

Comment: Do you know an other way to search on google after opening the page without clicking in the searchbox or pressing any buttons? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You could just use something in the form: `document.location = 'http://google.com/search?q=example';`

Comment: Thanks but I can't use your example since my knowledge about Javascript is low and your example does not meet my requirements. Can you change it so it works like I want it? Best regards, Jip

Comment: My example will change the current page to Google, it's the only way you can force the browser to do that. If you want a different answer _define requirements_.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you write will send F6 signal to your website, not your web browser. I doubt you can send keystore to web browser using javascript, it would be a security flaw?

The closest you can get is probably to implement your own search box (using Google API) and capture F6 event to focus to this search box